# Urls Unable To Be Found After Moving Django App To Another Machine

Tags: django, python-3.x

So I've built a Django app on my local machine that works perfectly. Using Bitvise, I've copied the files over to a server, and tried to run the server from there. Everything appears to run fine, I can access the admin page, however, I cannot get to the home page. When I attempt to visit any of the urls I've added, in the listed urls attempted, the only one listed is "^admin".

The following is my urls.py for the main app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('Home.urls', namespace='Home')),
    path('billing/', include('billing.urls', namespace='billing')),
    path('createquote/', include('createquote.urls', namespace='createquote')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The following are the installed apps on my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Home',
    'billing',
    'createquote',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And my ROOT_URLCONF:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'LNQuoteTool.urls'
```

The error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in project01.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, home/, didn't match any of these.
```

It should be noted that this is a 404 error.

Is there anything that appears blatantly wrong? How might I solve this?

Comment: What is exactly the error you get?

Comment: You sure you are using the right version of django?

Comment: I edited the original post to include the error that I was getting. When I posted the original post, I was on version 2.0.5, and what I built it on was 2.0.6. However, after upgrading pip, it still wasn't resolved.

Comment: It would appear that none of my apps are in the server when I run it, in spite of the folders and files all being there, and when I attempt to make a migration, it says that no changes were made.

Comment: I think this might've had something to do with the fact that my "allowed_hosts" dictionary is empty, but I've tried populating it with both the IP address of the server I've placed it on, as well as the address of the laptop I'm currently using (where the original code was made) and I cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

As it would turn out, the fix to this issue was to run the server with the IP address 0.0.0.0:8000/. The following was the exact command that allowed me to be able to connect to it from other devices:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000/
```

I wish I could provide a better explanation, as I'm not quite certain of the reason behind it (perhaps the 0's are stating to use the IP address of the machine). Thank you to everyone who attempted to help me solve this.